# I want to authenticate api by using public and private key for each user in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, public-key-encryption, api-authorization

I want to know how to implement public private key authentication for API & how to generate the new public private key pair and store them in the database so that at the time of API hit, i can retrieve them for authentication. Please correct me if i am wrong in my suggested approach and please share any example of code, so that i can understand how things are working.